# Theme a CCK input form in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, themes, cck

In my template.php file I've this:

```
function myadmintheme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'ccktype',
    ),
  );
}
```

And I've a ccktype.tpl.php in the same dir:

```
<b>works!</b>
```

But is not working, if I enter to node/add/ccktype I don't get the "works!" message..
I tried everything!

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theme function you need to override is ccktype_node_form, not node_form. All node forms maintained by the node module get mapped to the node_form function for building, but they still have unique form ids.

Comment: I tried that also, but didn't work. I forgot to say that in the "Administration theme" y check "Use administration theme for content editing" (that is obvious).

Comment: hey, I didn't notice this, but there is a very little change in the style when I use ccktype_node_form :D
It is not printing "WORKS!", but is better than nothing ;D

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
function myadmintheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'ccktype_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'ccktype',
    ),
  );
}
```

thanks a lot Eaton!

Comment: Glad you solved this! If Eaton helped you, then please mark his answer as correct; that will help others find this problem is solved and will grant Eaton reputation points for having helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

It started to work for me but after a loong set of trials. :)
I'm using Drupal 6 & I made the mistake of writing code for Drupal 5. I used `form_render` (wich is meant for D5) instead of `drupal_render` (for D6), in my node-minister-edit.php.

And the next change in template.php was function

```
waffles_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){ 
    return array( 'minister_node_form' => array( 'arguments' => array('form' => NULL), 'template' => 'node-minister-edit' ) ); 
}
```

See the array argument `template` is changed from `minister` to `node-minister-edit` which is my node specific template file. Here in `minister_node_form` , the first word 'minister' is my content type.

And as [Seb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76583/seb) said I cleared the caches before I started to use any such change.
Hope this helps others :)

The following items have helped me out:
1. http://drupal.org/node/601646 
2. http://drupal.org/node/98253

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see that Drupal's not caching your module. Go to Administer > Site Configuration > Performance, and clear all caches.

If that doesn't work, try renaming the file to node-add-ccktype.tpl.php.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't know... I had problems with that theme hook as well. Sorry I can't help anymore :(